# Decoding hex to coordinate

Tags: python, hex, endianness

I have a hex payload:

```
872fa5596122f23e24efb4fc1013b7000000000718
```

The lat and lng is in little endian and is at the following locations:

```
lng - binary[20:28]
lat - binary[28:32]
```

Im not sure how to get the correct results. I thought first I would have to change the hex to little endian? Then convert it to int?I tried this:

```
data = struct.unpack('<ll',binary[12:20])
```

**output:**

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Try encoding the binary first: `struct.unpack('<ll', binary.encode()[12:20])`. You're on Python 3, where strings != bytes.

Comment: Ah, I ddint realise, works with python 2.7

Comment: Am I followin the correct logic? First unpack then to binary?

Comment: No, first the string gets converted to bytes (from `"872fa5596122f23e24efb4fc1013b7000000000718"` to `b"872fa5596122f23e24efb4fc1013b7000000000718"`), then this gets unpacked.

Comment: how would you unpack it, with what arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert the hexdecimal representation into a bytes-object:

```
import codecs

binary = "872fa5596122f23e24efb4fc1013b7000000000718"
binary_bytes = codecs.decode(binary, 'hex')
print(binary_bytes)
# b'\x87/\xa5Ya"\xf2>$...
```

Then you can use `struct` to decode into integers or whatever:

```
import struct
# Guessed the offsets...
lng, lat = struct.unpack('<ll', binary_bytes[0:4] + binary_bytes[20:24])
print((lng, lat))
# (15003997831, 1056055905)
```